# Why does filter_var() encode quotes differently than htmlentities()?

Tags: php, encoding, html-entities, sanitization, filter-var

Why does filter_var()'s FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING filter encode single quotes as `&#39;` and double quotes as `&#34;` while htmlentities() encodes single quotes as `&#039;` and double quotes as `&quot;`?

Code Sample:

```
<?php
$string = "Well that's \"different.\"";

echo "filter_var: ".filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)."\n";
echo "htmlentities: ".htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES)."\n";
echo "htmlspecialchars: ".htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES)."\n";
```

Output:

```
filter_var: Well that&#39;s &#34;different.&#34; 
htmlentities: Well that&#039;s &quot;different.&quot; 
htmlspecialchars: Well that&#039;s &quot;different.&quot;
```

Comment: You can surely ask the same question to Rasmus Lerdorf.

Comment: In the end they're equivalent, so…

Comment: @deceze Is this Opinion-based?  I don't know how this one can be answered.

Comment: @deceze True, except if you are doing a string comparison between strings encoded in the two different ways.

Comment: @mick There *might* be a reason for it. I'd guess that `filter_*` is implemented very generically, replacing anything not within a certain whitelist with its character code; while `html*` is more specialised at HTML and knows all the aliases.

Comment: @PeterA then avoid making comparisons on strings being encoded via different functions.

Comment: Not sure why you'd ever want to compare encoded strings, especially when the encoding is volatile like HTML can be (Q.E.D.).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because short of personal declarations from the designers of php, any answer will be speculative/heresay/opinion-based/something else.

Comment: @deceze in this particular case the comparison was happening as part of a PHP Unit test against expected output. It has been updated to use the same encoding. Regardless of the reason for doing the comparison, I am trying to understand the reason for the two different encodings.

Comment: Well, knowing PHP I'd guess the implementations simply don't share a common backend and are implemented redundantly, differently. Whoever came up with the `filter_` functions implemented them without regard to how the existing `html*` functions did their job. I don't think the answer is any more meaningful than that.

Comment: @mickmackusa fair enough. I was trying to add a question about this because initially I couldn't figure out where the `&#39;` encoding was coming from and didn't find other questions  / answers noting that filter_var() encodes quotes in this way. Perhaps I should have asked that question instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `filter` extension has nothing to do with HTML processing. It doesn't use HTML entity conversion table. It is just a stupid encoding based on the ASCII value.

- `"` is 34 in ASCII
- `'` is 39 in ASCII

The same applies for any other character that the `filter` extension converts to HTML encoded form. It takes the ASCII numerical value in decimal, prepends `&#` and appends `;`. That's it! It's simple and efficient, even if it's not very correct.

No offence to anyone, but using this extension for anything HTML related is a rather dumb idea. The constant `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` is deprecated now and it will be removed in future versions of PHP. There exists a filter `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` which is just a wrapper around `htmlspecialchars()`, but I can't think of any reason to use this over the simple `htmlspecialchars()` function.

Some of these filters are a remainder from the era of lazy PHP. Developers used lazy approaches to security like magic quotes, which didn't provide enough security and often lead to more mess. These HTML filters were created with the same lazy approach in mind. It's better to provide something than nothing to mitigate XSS. However, this is definitely not the recommended practice anymore. Please format the output correctly using the appropriate functions to avoid XSS rather than relying on filters for sanitization.